# Merge two nodes in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some trouble with XSLT.

We have two nodes, like:

```
<main>
  <part>
    <block>1</block>
    <block>2</block>
    <block>3</block>
    <block>4</block>
  </part>
  <article>
    <block>A</block>
    <block>B</block>
    <block>B</block>
    <block>D</block>
  </article>
</main>
```

I need to view

```
<li>1</li>
<li>A</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>B</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>C</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>D</li>
```

At this moment wrote this, but it does not work as need:

```
<xsl:for-each select="part/*|article/*">
   <xsl:choose>                                     
      <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">
         <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>                                           
      </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Help me please.

Comment: The example does not explain the logic of the required transformation. Does the order matter here? Will the number of part blocks always be exactly the same as the number of article blocks?

Comment: The order is very important :( - it`s the task. Number of blocks of parts always will be the same as the number of articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very simple way to look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="main/part/block">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
            <li><xsl:value-of select="../../article/block[$i]"/></li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot!!! learn xsl two day for job and one day fighted with this task.